# Memory management with pointers created using "new" in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I have a base class where 2 pointers are declared in the header. The pointers are then initialized with the "new" keyword in a method of the base class and deleted with "delete" in the destructor of the base class.

I also have a derived class that inherits from the base class. I declare a pointer there as well. Depending on a boolean, this pointer is assigned to either pointer of the base class. However, this results in a segfault when the destructor of the base class is called.

My understanding is that this happens because the derived class will delete the pointer automatically before the destructor of the base class is called. When "delete" is called in the base class, then this area of memory has already been freed and a segfault results.

What is the correct way of doing this? My aim is to have a pointer in the derived class that can flexibly equal one of the pointers initialized in the base class.

Comment: It is better to show code (even if it's only pseudo code) than to describe it in prose.

Comment: Psychic debugger says: "you're `delete`ing the dynamic data in both the derived _and_ the base class"

Answer (score 2):

Either do not delete the pointer in the derived class or use standard smart pointer `std::shared_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

Your base class should probably have a virtual destructor, then you should override the destructor in your derived class to make sure everything gets deleted in the order you expect.

But it's hard to tell what's happening without seeing the code, so that's just a thought...